# Events in the tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

I am having a little trouble understanding what exactly is the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Just so we are all on the same page, my book defined the tail $\sigma$-algebra like this:

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variable defined on $(\Omega,
>  \mathcal{A}, P)$. Define $\mathcal{B}_n = \sigma(X_n)$, $\mathcal{C}_n
>  = \sigma(\cup_{p \ge n} \mathcal B_p)$, $\mathcal C_\infty = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal C_n$.  $\mathcal C_\infty$ is called the tail $\sigma$-algebra.

Suppose now that $X_n$ are independent. 
I am having trouble understanding why the following are true (we are talking about the consequences of Kolmogorov's Zero-One Law):
$$\{ \omega: \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) \text{ exists} \} \in \mathcal C_\infty$$
$$\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n \ \ \liminf_{x \to \infty} X_n \ \ \limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \sum_{p \le n} X_p \ \ \liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \sum_{p \le n} X_p \text{  are $\mathcal C_\infty$ measurable} $$

I don't have any intuition about why these are true nor what exactly is a tail $\sigma$-algebra apart from the definition, which does not inspire me that much.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which one of these events depend on $X_1$?

Comment: @Did The first event does not, I guess. The others are r.v. which do depend on $X_1$.. Maybe I am misinterpreting what you said. To be honest I'm a little confused (if that wasn't clear already!)
Anyhow I'd appreciate a comment about the downvote and the vote to close, so I can improve something :)

Comment: Is $\limsup X_n$ depending on $X_1$?

Comment: @Did No but $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac 1n \sum_{p \le n} X_p$ is. Why is it useful to know wether it depends on $X_1$ or not?

Comment: So $\limsup X_n$ does not depend on $X_1$ (although you did not say why). But why do you think that $\limsup\frac1n\sum\limits_{p=1}^nX_p$ does depend on $X_1$?

Comment: @Did Because if we suppose $X_i \ge 0$, the fact that $X_1 = 1$ means that then $\limsup \frac 1n \sum_{p=1}^n X_p$ cannot be $0$. Well actually what I've just said is true for a finite $n$ but taking the $\limsup$ changes things. Maybe $X_1$ does not matter because it will be divided by $n \to \infty$ so it does not matter what value $X_1$ (or $X_k$ for a fixed $k$) is going to take. I should think more about it, but I don't see how it relates to the tail $\sigma$-algebra

Comment: You do not see how random variables measurable with respect to $(X_k)_{k\geqslant1}$ but independent of $(X_k)_{k\leqslant n}$, for every $n$, relate to the tail sigma-algebra? Well, they do, they do very much...

Comment: @Did I didn't doubt they did! I just can't see the connection. Now that you stated it that way I can think of this pseudo-justification: those random variable are $\mathcal C_n$ measurable for every $n$. But since they are independent of $(X_k)_{k \leqslant n}$ for every $n$, when one takes the intersection of  $\mathcal C_n$ (so you "cut off" the firsts one) it does not change anything because they do not depend on the first $k$ sigma algebrae. Is this more or less the reason? I should think of a formal way to prove that though

Comment: Intuitively, an event is in the tail sigma algebra if you can drop first $X$'s (any finite number) in the sequence and the event does not change. This is closely related to exchangeable sigma algebra...

Comment: For example, let $A_k=\{\lim\sum_{n\ge k}X_k\text{ exists}\}$. Then $A_1=A_2=A_k\in\sigma(X_k,X_{k+1},...)$ (because the series converges iff its tail converges). So, $A_1\in\bigcap_{k\ge 1}\sigma(X_k,X_{k+1},...)\equiv \mathcal C_\infty$

Comment: @d.k.o. I think it is a little clearer now. I would be very grateful if you could make an answer and expand a little over what you just said! :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer follows the idea of what @d.k.o. pointed out. For example, for the statement

$$\{ \omega: \exists \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n(\omega) \} \in  C_\infty$$

we can argue as follows:

For each n, $X_{m}$ with $m \ge n$ is measurable for the $\sigma$-field ${C}_n
 = \sigma(\cup_{p \ge n} B_{p})$. Now we use the following fact:

> *The set of convergence of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable*

Therefore the set of convergence of the sequence ${X_{m}}$ with $m \ge n$ is measurable in $C_{n}$. As this set of convergence does not change with n, it follows it belongs to $C_\infty$.

When you understand this proof the rest is easier. Let's prove that:

> $\limsup_{n \to \infty} X_n$ is a measurable function in $C_\infty$.

$[\lim sup_{n \to \infty} X_{n} < c]=[\lim sup_{k \to \infty, k \ge n} X_{n} < c]$ which belongs to $C_{n}$ and the statement follows.