# Why is $(F_n \in \mathbb{B} i.o)$ in the tail-algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

I don't understand the following argument:

"For any $m \ge 1$, $$(F_n i.o) = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k=n}^\infty F_n = \cap_{n=m}^\infty \cup_{k = n}^\infty F_n,$$ and so $(F i.o)$ is in the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $1_{(F_n)}$"

How does that follow? I guess the reason is I probably don't understand the tail-algebra. It seems really abstract: $\cap_{n=1}^\infty \sigma(1_{F_n}, 1_{F_{n+1}},....)$

EDIT: The $F$-sequence is independnet.

Comment: Maybe you can find some help here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047306/events-in-the-tail-sigma-algebra

Comment: I get intuitively that if it only depends on the "tail indicies" (which it does since $m \ge 1$is arbitrary), then its in the tail-algebra, but i want the formal proof. Or is this itself the formal proof?

Comment: I suppose you are looking at the proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma. I will write it up for you in a moment.

Comment: Yes, it's Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: As an interest - what book are you using?

Comment: It's available online. "Advanced Probability Theory", Sokol, Rønn-Nielsen.

Comment: Wonderful - I could recognise the formulation. I am a master student at Copenhagen University, where Rønn-Nielsen is positioned and Sokol has studied, so I used the book myself 2 years ago.

Comment: Cool coincidence. I am not a student there, I just found it online and am self-studying.

Comment: Sound swell. If you message me your e-mail, I can send you some of the material that the authors (or other lecturers) have used in their courses in connection with the book.

Answer (score 1):

First: You do not need independence of the F-sequence. You are probably considering a proof of the Borel-Cantelli lemma, where this requirement is needed later.

The tail-$\sigma$-algebra of a sequence of events $(F_n)$ is defined as

$C_\infty = \cap_{n=1}^\infty \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots)$,

where $X_n=\mathbb{1}_{F_n}$.

Now for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$,

$(F_n \, \text{i.o.})=\cap_{n=1}^\infty \cup_{k=n}^\infty F_k = \cap_{n=m}^\infty \cup_{k=n}^\infty F_k \in \sigma(X_m,X_{m+1},\ldots)$,

as $X_k=\mathbb{1}_{F_k}$ and $\cup_{k=n}^\infty F_k \in \sigma(X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots)$. As $m\in\mathbb{N}$ is arbitrary, $(F_n \, \text{i.o.})$ will be in $\sigma(X_m,X_{m+1},\ldots)$ for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, thus especially it is in $C_\infty$.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: I am using the definition of intersection, that is $x\in \cap_{n\in\mathbb{N}} A_n$ iff $x \in A_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.