# Events in Tail $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be real valued random variables. Put $\mathfrak S_n=\sigma (X_n)$ and $S_n=X_1+X_2+...+X_n$. Let $\mathfrak T_n=\sigma (X_{n+1},X_{n+2},...)$ and define the tail $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak T=\cap _n \mathfrak T_n$.

The book I am reading now says : $\{\limsup S_n>b\}\notin \mathfrak T$

But I don't get why this holds. Intuitively, this event seems to be unaffected by first finite happenings... Could you give me an example or explanation? Thank you in advance.

Edit:

For example, let $X_n =^{dist} U_{(-1,1)}$ for all $n$, assuming that they are **not** independent and let $b=0$.

Is is still true that $\{\limsup S_n>b\}\notin \mathfrak T$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047306/events-in-the-tail-sigma-algebra/1592010#1592010 may be of help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(This answers the original version of the question.)

Take $X_n(\omega) = 0$ for all $n \ge 2, \omega \in \Omega$.  It's a zero-valued function with respect to $\omega \in \Omega$, so it's a real-valued nonnegative random variable, so that $S_n = X_1$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.  It's clear that $S_n$ *depends entirely on $X_1$* and $$\{\limsup S_n > b\} = \{\limsup X_1 > b\} \notin \mathfrak T.$$

Comment: It seems that whether the statement is true or not depends heavily on the choice of $\{X_n\}$... am I right?

Comment: For example, if we set $X_n =^{dist} U_{(-1,1)}$ and $b=0$, is the statement still true?

Comment: For the first question, the statement in the question concerns *every* random variables $X_1,\dots$, and I've found a counterexample, so a logical answer is false.

Comment: OK. The book I am reading is careless in giving the statements. It should have said that there exist $\{X_n\}$ and $b\in R$ such that blah blah. Anyways your answer is correct.

Comment: @Mhr You may refer to the [French Wiki for Kolmogorov's 0-1 law](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loi_du_z%C3%A9ro-un_de_Kolmogorov#Exemples) for an explanation about $\{\sum_n X_n > b\} \notin \mathfrak T$

Comment: Thank you. So it depends on the choice of $X_n$ and $b$.